# What's the correct term for a 700x23c disc wheel?

Tags: wheels

I'm looking to convert my fixie to a front wheel disc brake set up. I've narrowed down a fork that looks promising, and I'm on to the wheel.

I've got 700x23c tires I want to keep, so I want the wheel to fit. I understand the hub needs to be disc brake compatible. When I search for it (700x23c disc wheel OR 700x23c disc hub wheel).

What's the right term to search for that I'll get results for the product type that I'm looking for?

Comment: MTB 29'er is a 700C. Also what terms do Cyclocross use - 29'er or 700C? Therefore 29'er might help, as MTB almost exclusively use disks - although wider rims.

Comment: Also note that the x23 refers to tire size and not rim size (and that you can fit a range of tires onto a rim, to a point.) You need rims that are between 13-17mm wide internal measure (maybe 15-19mm wide external) to support a weenie little 23c tire. That is where you're going to get stuck, because hardly anybody rides disc wheels with skinny tires. You may have to liberate yourself from the 23mm tires or have a front wheel made to order, unfortunately.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll probably need a new fork.  (Trying to save the tires is probably false economy, BTW.)

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned about the fork already. It's easier if my front and rear wheels have the same tires than having to buy different widths.

Comment: @WTHarper so I should just be searching for a 700c (or 29er) wheel and then looking at the specific specs? Is disc wheel or disc hub wheel still the right term?

Comment: @Robin Ashe searches for 700x23 disc wheel will probably throw a lot of time-trial/triathlon style wheels into the results. These will still be fairly pricey as the UCI just began allowing disc brakes on cyclocross bikes in the 2011-2012 season, so they are still a bit of a novelty.  You could always scrounge up a disc brake compatible hub with the same number of holes as your old wheel, and build it into the rim you've already got if it's in good shape.

Comment: Which fork did you find? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: @Mac The On One Pompetamine, it comes in black and white (I was specifically looking for white). The Kona P2 was another option, in black only, but it comes in a few variations for wheel size and also has canti versions.

Answer (score 6):

A search for [cyclocross disk wheels](https://www.google.com/search?q=road%20rim%20with%20disk%20hub&aq=f&oq=road%20rim%20with%20disk%20hub&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.3789&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=cyclocross%20disk%20wheels&oq=cyclocross%20disk&gs_l=serp.3.1.0l4.17072.22627.0.24796.15.8.0.7.7.0.95.576.8.8.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.6.psy-ab.f8XNuB5h824&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.cGE&fp=5d76e49206851269&biw=1454&bih=726) turned up plenty of options.  Maybe [this wheel](http://www.performancebike.com/bikes/ProductDisplay?storeId=10052&langId=-1&catalogId=10551&productId=1123592&utm_source=Google_Product_Search&utm_medium=pla&utm_campaign=datafeed&cm_mmc=Google_Product_Search-_-PLA-_-Datafeed-_-Stan%27s%20Alpha%20340%20Disc%20Front%20Wheel%20Null%20Front&CAWELAID=1304360140&catargetid=1630495989&cagpspn=pla) would work for you.

Comment: That wheel does look like it could do the trick. I think I might have to ask a new question about the quality I can expect from various price ranges.